# mysql: keeping local mysql database and remote server database synced up

Tags: mysql, localhost, remote-server

I am kind of a amateur at web development. But it seems like most people develop on their local machines and the upload to their remote servers when everything is ready.  I want to start doing this. I've installed Xampp (Apache) on my local machine. But in order for this to really work, i need the the mysql databases that already exist on my remote server to be "synched" or "duplicated" on my local machine. But I'm finding this somewhat hard to figure out.

First, Should I be using mysql "reduplication" feature (with my remote server as master) and local machine as slave? Or is there a better way to do this? Should I be synchronizing instead of reduplicating

Second, Is anyone willing to give me a quick description of how I achieve this "reduplication" or "synchronization"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be tempting, but it's hopeless to try to keep the database in two places. Instead, always keep the database on the server because it's much easier to develop and debug your code if it's in just one place. "Resynch" and "reduplicate" and all that business is just too much trouble, as you are discovering. The DB is going to end up on the server anyway, so you may as well put it there right now.

Also, you will not need a web server on your local machine, which will unburden you.

This next is applicable if you are writing CGI. If you aren't sure whether or not you are writing CGI, then you are not (well, probably not). {

If you mainain just one database and it lives on your server, you'll be able to write one piece of portable code that will run equally well on your local machine and on your server. This is a huge win, take my word for it.

To get this working, you will need the mysql library on your local machine; no other mysql component is needed there. The mysql server will run on your server only.

Read up on mysql "connector" for the language you're using.

}

Comment: Dear Pete, that is good to hear. But can I follow up. If I'm running my script (which does a mysql query) on my local machine, but my database is on my remote server, how will I be able to see that data when I viewing my site locally?

Comment: @Jeff -- Something must be missing in my explanation that will let you fill in the blind spot you're looking at. "how will I be able to see that data when I viewing my site locally?" Ans: if your connection to the remote MySQL serveris  working right, then viewing table data locally is ***just the same*** as if your MySQL table were local. Your MySQL library makes the localness or remoteness of your table invisible; it makes it look as if your table were local. You might want to give it a try and see what happens. Once you get over this one little conceptual hump, understanding will surface.